Best practice to open files for use in a gui
My application opens a video file, plays frames in a GUI, then closes it. The logic is like this
import cv2
try: 
    self.vid = cv2.VideoCapture(local_file)
    self.play_frame()
finally: 
    # vid.release()

But the problem is that the logic for start_playback() is asynchronous, eg
def play_frame(self):
    ok, frame = self.vid.read() 
    self.tkframe['image'] = ...     # display frame
    if ok:                          # next frame
        tkframe.after( 33, lambda:self.play_frame() )
    # else: vid.release() ? 

And my question is: is there a safe way to make sure the video gets closed? Clearly try...finally is not going to work here, as it would close the video after the first frame. And I don't see how I can make a with statement work.
I am currently using else: vid.release() when the last frame is read. However, the file keeps getting left open, for example when an exception occurs somewhere else in the application, or the app closes prematurely.
Edit
in answer to @john gordon's comment
I am running the app from an interactive console -- I set a variable for the video filename, call the player, and it exits back to the console.
I then run another function that overwrites the video, and this function fails with "This file is already open in another application, python.exe".
If I close or restart the python console, it closes the file, but then I lose all my variables.
Anyhow this is about best practices for ensuring the video gets closed.

or the app closes prematurely  How can the file still be open when the app is closed?  I don't understand.  What actual behavior do you see that makes you think the file is "being left open"?

try ... finally with no  except branch makes no sense. This is the same as not to use try.

@JohnGordon - I answered in an edit, but in brief it's being run from an interactive console. I need to overwrite the file after the GUI exits.

@YuriGinsburg Example of try...finally without except - it is supposed to be used for this exact purpose, for closing a file at the end. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tryfinally_block.htm
